# How to delete rows from tables which is referenced each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, multi-table-delete

I want to do this:

```
delete from table1 a,table2 b, table3  c 
 where a.col1 = b.col1 
   and b.col2 = c.col2 
   and a.co3 <> 8001;
```

But its giving me an error.

Comment: What is the error (and what do you want to happen)

Comment: What does the schema look like? Which tables have foreign keys?

Comment: a.col1 primary key 
b.col1 forien key, primary key
c.col2 foriend key

Comment: well, i belive you can disable the FK and do ur stuff and once done, bring back to FK

so pseudo SQL would be 


DROP FK; 
Delete ....; 
Delete ....; 
CREATE FK;

Answer (score 3):

delete the lowest level first and move up from there, one delete per level, to the highest level:

```
DELETE FROM ChildTable WHERE ParentID=...

DELECT FROM ParentTable WHERE ParentID=...
```

Comment: Actually you can do that by use of the cascade function as mentioned by thekaido

Answer (score 2):

You could turn cascade deletes on then delete the parent record.

Comment: +1 I was going to write exact same answer. That is the only automated way of deleting related records. Other option was depicted in the first answer.

Comment: Being explicit is the *best* answer.  `CASCADE ON DELETE` can cause problems if someone absent-mindedly triggers it, and SQL Server 2005 `CASCADE ON DELETE` can be applied but won't work when it's a self-referencial relationship.

Comment: Valid point OMG Ponies but also there are often times though when deleting a parent record it wouldn't make sense to keep the child records at all and casade on delete makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify to what each table has a foreign key and on which field, I'll take a guess:

```
Delete TableC
Where Exists( Select 1 From TableA Where TableA.Col1 = TableC.Col2 And TableA.Col3 <> '8001' )

Delete TableB
Where Exists( Select 1 From TableA Where TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col2 And TableA.Col3 <> '8001' )

Delete TableA
Where Col3 <> '8001'
```

Answer (score 0):

delete A from table1 a,table2 b, table3  c
 where a.col1 = b.col1
   and b.col2 = c.col2
   and a.co3 <> 8001;